# Intellij Cannot resolve symbol 'ucp'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Был обычный проект, сделал из-него Maven проект. Все компилится, все работает. Но Intellij не видит оракловских пакетов. На

```
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;
```

выделяет красным `ucp` и пишет

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ucp'

И соответственно при объявлении

```
PoolDataSource poolConnections
```

выделяет красным `PoolDataSource` и пишет

> Cannot resolve symbol 'PoolDataSource'

Пакеты добавлены в зависимости

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

логин и пароль для maven-репозитория оракла указаны. Сами `jar` я вижу в локальном репозитории и еще раз-все компилится в той-же Intellij и запускается

`Invalidate Caches / Restart` делал - не помогло

Comment: Вам нужно заимпортить проект. Обычно Idea сама предлагает окошко import project, но иногда нужно явно зайти в View -> Tool Windows -> maven projects и нажать на закрученую стрелочку

Comment: @Uraty Не помогло. Это же можно сделать из контекстного меню по pom файлу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

не нужно добавлять в свой проект. Она сама подтягивается пакетом `ucp`. Удалил ее из pom файла и оставил только

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Перекомпилировал проект и проблема пропала